# Can I get the measurements for eyes using ARKit 2

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, iphone-x, ios12

I am working on a project which requires size of each eye and distance between the eyes using ARKit and True depth Camera on iPhone X with iOS 12 beta 4 on Xcode 10 beta 4.

As I am new to ARKit, I am searching the solution online with very little understanding. However, I came across a [demo code on apple developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/creating_face_based_ar_experiences). In that code, I tried to fetch the required values.

[Also referred to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48156956/3396270) by @rickster

I worked on ARSCNFaceGeometry and ARFaceAnchor to fetch few values.

```
func update(withFaceAnchor anchor: ARFaceAnchor) {
    let faceGeometry = geometry as! ARSCNFaceGeometry
    faceGeometry.update(from: anchor.geometry)
    print("\nLook at Point :", anchor.lookAtPoint, "\nLeft :", anchor.leftEyeTransform, "\nRight :", anchor.rightEyeTransform)
}
```

Output:

> Look at Point : float3(0.14502259, 0.2905016, 0.97809345)
>
> Left : simd_float4x4([[0.99312633, -0.030915117, -0.11289084, 0.0)],
>   [0.0, 0.9644885, -0.26412484, 0.0)], [0.11704737, 0.26230934,
>   0.9578589, 0.0)], [0.03311049, 0.028666705, 0.028539032, 1.0)]])
>
> Right : simd_float4x4([[0.9830616, -0.047965277, -0.17688738, 0.0)],
>   [0.0, 0.96514606, -0.26171172, 0.0)], [0.18327524, 0.25727874,
>   0.94879806, 0.0)], [-0.032072492, 0.028482603, 0.028181288, 1.0)]])

Questions

1. How to translate these values to make use of it and get some
   coordinates?
2. Will this code help me to achieve the size of each eye and distance
   between the eyes. If no, then what can I do to get the measurements?

Answer (score 3):

In ARKit 2 / Xcode 10 beta 6 / iOS 12 "lookAtPoint" is nulled; but I am able to get the "leftEyeTransform" and "rightEyeTransform", and can then calculate the inter-eye distance using this code (tested on two people at varying distances and validated with a ruler!):

```
func update(withFaceAnchor anchor: ARFaceAnchor) {
    let faceGeometry = occlusionNode.geometry as! ARSCNFaceGeometry
    faceGeometry.update(from: anchor.geometry)
    print("\nLook at Point:", anchor.lookAtPoint, "\nLeft:", anchor.leftEyeTransform, "\nRight:", anchor.rightEyeTransform)

var leftEyePosition = SCNVector3(anchor.leftEyeTransform.columns.3.x, anchor.leftEyeTransform.columns.3.y, anchor.leftEyeTransform.columns.3.z)
var rightEyePosition = SCNVector3(anchor.rightEyeTransform.columns.3.x, anchor.rightEyeTransform.columns.3.y, anchor.rightEyeTransform.columns.3.z)
let d = distance(float3(leftEyePosition), float3(rightEyePosition))
print("\nInter-eye distance in centimeters: ", d * 100)
```

}

Some sample output:

```
Look at Point: float3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) 
Left: simd_float4x4([[0.9997796, -0.0031222918, 0.020761598, 0.0)], [0.0, 0.98888004, 0.14871553, 0.0)], [-0.020995062, -0.14868274, 0.98866206, 0.0)], [0.031608228, 0.031428084, 0.026632207, 1.0)]]) 
Right: simd_float4x4([[0.99887705, 0.007054036, -0.04684897, 0.0)], [0.0, 0.9888536, 0.14889139, 0.0)], [0.047377057, -0.1487242, 0.98774314, 0.0)], [-0.031623494, 0.03171173, 0.02669965, 1.0)]])

Inter-eye distance in centimeters:  6.32324
```

NOTE:

Answer (score 2):

One line solution for pupils distance:

```
simd_distance(faceAnchor.rightEyeTransform.columns.3, faceAnchor.leftEyeTransform.columns.3)
```

Multiple it by 100 to get the answer in centimeters.
As mentioned above there is no a simple way to measure iris or pupils size, for that you need to develop an algorithm that will do the following:

1) finds circles and filters the one that describes an iris

2) use ARKit to calculate the pixel to millimeter value and use it to calculate the iris size

Answer (score 1):

you can get the vector3 from the transform :

```
var leftEyePosition = SCNVector3(leftTransform.columns.3.x, leftTransform.columns.3.y, leftTransform.columns.3.z)

var rightEyePosition = SCNVector3(rightTransform.columns.3.x, rightTransform.columns.3.y, rightTransform.columns.3.z)
```

then you can get the distance form 2 SCNVector3 like this.

```
let d = distance(float3(leftEyePosition), float3(rightEyePosition))
```

the result will be in meters, so you may want to divide d by 100

Comment: Will this be the distance between two eyes..?

Comment: this will give you the distance between the origin of the eye spheres, which is probably not far off the interpupullary distance if this is what you are asking? if you need the distance between the eyes (edge to edge), you can subtract the diameter of 1 eye.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way of actually getting the size of the pupils themselves. See this StackOverFlow thread and the answer provided by Rickster for more info: [Getting The Sizes Of The Eyes In ARKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50286403/can-catransform3d-be-used-to-get-eye-size-dimensions-in-face-mesh)

Getting the estimated distance between the eyes however is possible using the `leftEyeTransform` and `rightEyeTransforms` which are simply:

> transform matrixes indicating the position and orientation of the
>   face's left and right eyes.

[image]

What you are interested in is the 3rd Columns from these which contain the data we need.

A simple way to calculate the distance is to use the GLK helpers which dont require any additional extensions.

As such an example might look like something like so:

```
//----------------------
//MARK ARSCNViewDelegate
//----------------------

extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate{

    /// Creates A GLKVector3 From a Simd_Float4
    ///
    /// - Parameter transform: simd_float4
    /// - Returns: GLKVector3
    func glkVector3FromARFaceAnchorTransform(_ transform: simd_float4) -> GLKVector3{

        return GLKVector3Make(transform.x, transform.y, transform.z)
    }

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        //1. Check We Have A Valid ARFaceAnchor
        guard let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor else { return }


        //2. Get The Position Of The Left & Right Eyes
        let leftEyePosition = glkVector3FromARFaceAnchorTransform(faceAnchor.leftEyeTransform.columns.3)
        let righEyePosition = glkVector3FromARFaceAnchorTransform(faceAnchor.rightEyeTransform.columns.3)

        //3. Calculate The Distance Between Them
        let distanceBetweenEyesInMetres = GLKVector3Distance(leftEyePosition, righEyePosition)
        let distanceBetweenEyesInCM = distanceBetweenEyesInMetres/100
        print("The Distance Between The Eyes Is Approximatly \(distanceBetweenEyesInCM)")

    }

}
```

Hope it helps...