# ARKit 2.0 – "lookAtPoint" property always gets zeros

Tags: swift, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit, ios12

I am using ARKit 2 under iOS 12 (16A5288q), building with Xcode 10 beta 6, running on an iPhone X, and `lookAtPoint` is *always* zeroes.

I access the face data (in Swift) with:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor else { return }

    FaceAnchorsProcessedCount = FaceAnchorsProcessedCount + 1
    let rightEyeTransform: simd_float4x4 = faceAnchor.rightEyeTransform
    let leftEyeTransform:  simd_float4x4 = faceAnchor.leftEyeTransform
    let lookAtPoint:       simd_float3   = faceAnchor.lookAtPoint
}
```

And I get data like:

```
rightEyeTransform    simd_float4x4    \n[ [9.999874e-01, 0.000000e+00, 5.010252e-03, -3.208227e-02],\n  [2.375229e-04, 9.988756e-01, -4.740678e-02, 2.703529e-02],\n  [-5.004618e-03, 4.740737e-02, 9.988630e-01, 2.525132e-02],\n  [0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 1.000000e+00] ]\n    
leftEyeTransform     simd_float4x4    \n[ [9.978353e-01, 0.000000e+00, -6.576237e-02, 3.208223e-02],\n  [-3.110934e-03, 9.988804e-01, -4.720329e-02, 2.703534e-02],\n  [6.568874e-02, 4.730569e-02, 9.967182e-01, 2.525137e-02],\n  [0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 1.000000e+00] ]\n    
lookAtPoint          simd_float3      (0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00)
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is this a known bug?

UPDATED 4 Oct 2018
I did a simple test of `lookAtPoint` today. I moved my face close to the handset, and then farther away, and close again; repeatedly.
The *minimum* z for lookAtPoint was 38.59 inches, and the *max* was 39.17 inches (converted from meters).

The **actual** distances, measured with a measuring tape, were ~4.5 inches and ~33 inches.

Apple's declaration that `lookAtPoint` will "[...] estimate what point, relative to the face, the user's eyes are focused upon." does not seem to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Today iOS 12 was released, along with XCode 10 (replacing the beta releases). I tested accessing `lookAtPoint` with these new releases, and am now getting *populated* vectors.

Swift code:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor else { return }

    let lookAtPoint: simd_float3 = faceAnchor.lookAtPoint
    os_log("lookAtPoint: %.12f,%.12f,%.12f", type: .debug, lookAtPoint.x, lookAtPoint.y, lookAtPoint.z)
```

Log output:

```
2018-09-17 16:17:12.097369-0700 EyeSync[512:41060] lookAtPoint: 0.049317009747,-0.004630976822,0.981833696365
2018-09-17 16:17:12.113925-0700 EyeSync[512:41060] lookAtPoint: 0.050239805132,-0.006484962534,0.981752157211
2018-09-17 16:17:12.130867-0700 EyeSync[512:41060] lookAtPoint: 0.051697697490,-0.011350239627,0.981206715107
2018-09-17 16:17:12.147272-0700 EyeSync[512:41060] lookAtPoint: 0.052744854242,-0.012763299979,0.981896817684
2018-09-17 16:17:12.163683-0700 EyeSync[512:41060] lookAtPoint: 0.054889015853,-0.015469233505,0.982917487621
2018-09-17 16:17:12.180636-0700 EyeSync[512:41060] lookAtPoint: 0.056391790509,-0.017265520990,0.983718335629
2018-09-17 16:17:12.197387-0700 EyeSync[512:41060] lookAtPoint: 0.059109147638,-0.018527992070,0.983208477497
2018-09-17 16:17:12.214021-0700 EyeSync[512:41060] lookAtPoint: 0.061453290284,-0.019032688811,0.981536626816
2018-09-17 16:17:12.230689-0700 EyeSync[512:41060] lookAtPoint: 0.063107110560,-0.019657038152,0.978309571743
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I tried it one month ago and I could say that you're absolutely right – at the moment the `lookAtPoint` instance property doesn't work or even stubbed out. Now it always returns `float3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`.

I guess Apple hasn't implemented it yet (it's in beta state). `Cross eyes' detection` is an ARKit's feature that we'll seemingly see in iOS 12 final stable release.

At the moment I don't have a Mac and I can't check it, so try to use `open class` with open instance properties like these:

```
open class ARFaceAnchor: ARTrackable {
    open var leftEyeTransform: simd_float4x4 { get } 
    open var rightEyeTransform: simd_float4x4 { get } 
    open var lookAtPoint: simd_float3 { get }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: There is seemingly an example of lookAtPoint working here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51531578/can-i-get-the-measurements-for-eyes-using-arkit-2>

However, I downloaded the same sample code from Apple Developer, added the on-liner to print, and got zeroes, again, for lookAtPoint. 
Was it working earlier, and then stopped?

Comment: Thanks, @andy, but to me as a beginning Swift programmer (I am more of  C and Java guy) this is a bit obscure as a code snippet; I am not quite able to figure out how to use it in the context I am exploring. :-(

Comment: I did a simple test of lookAtPoint today. I moved my face close to the handset, and then farther away, and close again; repeatedly.
The _minimum_ z for lookAtPoint was 38.59 inches, and the _max_ was 39.17 inches (converted from meters).

Comment: And what's the result?

Comment: I did a simple test of `lookAtPoint` today. I moved my face close to the handset, and then farther away, and close again; repeatedly.
The _minimum_ z for lookAtPoint was 38.59 inches, and the _max_ was 39.17 inches (converted from meters).

The **actual** distances, measured with a measuring tape, were ~4.5 inches and ~33 inches.

Apple's declaration that `lookAtPoint` will "[...] estimate what point, relative to the face, the user's eyes are focused upon." does not seem to be correct.

Comment: That's interesting. Please post it in your question as UPDATED or P.S. issue.